# I am new to ML I dont understand that sklearn part

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

what we are doing on line 10 `train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2)`?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB as gnb
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\avina\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\program2_diabetes-20191105T144141Z-001\program2_diabetes\die.csv')
print (data.describe())

features = ['Pregnancies', 'Glucose', 'BloodPressure', 'SkinThickness', 'BMI', 'Age', 'Insulin', 'DiabetesPedigreeFunction']
target = 'Class'
train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2)
clf = gnb().fit(train[features], train[target]) 
y_predicted = clf.predict(test[features])
print ("Accuracy ",round(accuracy_score(test[target], y_predicted)*100,2)," %")
```

Comment: we split the data into two sets to train on one and validate on the other. The test size is 20% of  the total size

Comment: Did you check the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2)`

It is splitting your dataframe into 2 smaller ones, one that contains 80% of the original (train) and 20% (test).

You can check with shape and assert everything is there with

`train.shape[0] + test.shape[0] == data.shape[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind this is to split the data into two sets:

- Training set: the set we use to train our model in order to tune the value of its parameters to adjust the data.
- Validation set: the set we use to test the perfomance of our model adjusting data that it has not seen before.

The performance of the model in the training set only indicates that the model is good/bad for those data, but if we want to adress the generalization of the model we have to test it with new unseen data.